# OleDbDataAdapter Fill method bad performance

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, oledb

I'm using OleDbDataAdapter class to get data from an Access (.mdb) file.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+Environment.CurrentDirectory+"\\Data.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=pass");
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
        oda.Fill(dt);
        oda.Dispose();
        com.Parameters.Clear();
        con.Close();
        return dt;
```

The problem is that by debugging I found out, `oda.Fill(dt)` takes a very long time to execute. (around 10 seconds)

I have 50,000 records in the database and I only need to retrieve 1 row.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your `query`? Is your table has indexing or something?

Comment: If you use a `DataReader` you can read only the first row and not have to deal with other records that you don't need.

Comment: this is my query: `Select mname, received_date, measure_date, height, weight, calory, pbf_rate, std_weight, fat from member_data where id_number = 1000`

Comment: And this query returns only one row?  How long does it take if you run it directly in Access?

Comment: In Access it works instantly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is one row try using a data reader as shown below, of your you will need to adjust pieces like database name, field list etc.

Note I write output to the IDE Output window so have it open when trying this with your code/data.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out id))
        {
            OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
            Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
            Builder.DataSource = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.mdb");

            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(Builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                string selectStatement = "SELECT UserName, JoinMonth FROM Users WHERE Identifier = @Identifier";
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { CommandText = selectStatement, Connection = cn })
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { ParameterName = "@Identifier", DbType = DbType.Int32, Value = id });
                    cn.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        dr.Read();
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not located");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```